# Enterprise Architect Shape Script DrawNativeShape() Function does not work

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created a new profile for Enterprise Architect. It defines a stereotype for "Requirement".
Modifying the default shape of "Requirement", I'm dealing with Shape Script. Calling the function "DrawNativeShape()" does not raise an error, neither has any effect! 
In fact I expect the code below to display the default shape of the element, but it does not so that the diagram looks empty.

```
shape main{  
     DrawNativeShape();
}
```

Comment: Is the requirement element on the diagram, just drawn with transparent stroke and fill?

Answer (score 1):

The **DrawNativeShape** command is effectively saying "draw the shape exactly as you would if it didn't have a shape script". You say that that is what is happening. I don't see a problem.

There are two main uses for **DrawNativeShape**:

- It can be used to apply conditional shapes to an element. What you do is test some condition and depending on the answer either draw a shape or call **DrawNativeShape**.
- It can be used to apply conditional colour to an element. Call **SetFillColor** followed by **DrawNativeShape** and the element will be drawn with default appearance but using the colour specified by the shape script.

Comment: I think I've not explained the problem well. Calling the DrawNativeShape, does NOT draw anything at all. Even the default shape is not displayed!

Comment: @Siavash what version of EA  are you running and what kind of element are you applying the shape script to?

Comment: I'm using EA Version "8.0.864" that includes "EAShapeScript 1.0". The main element type is "Requirement" and I have defined a new stereotype based on it.